# I have a Frigidaire oven and the timer will not beep what do I need to do

Tags: oven

I have a Frigidaire oven and the timer want beep when it's done.  What do I need to do?

Comment: can you tell us the model so we can look up

Comment: Might be cheaper to just get a simple kitchen timer if the only problem is the beep is gone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to call their customer service and ask them  or research the oven operating instruction. That's what we'd have to do for you.

Comment: maybe you disabled it

Comment: There are often several non-obvious founctions involving weird combinations of buttons that you'll find in your operators/owners manual for the stove. Turning off the sound could well be one. It's probably not Sabbath mode, since that usually disables the display as well (or minimizes it to a static display)

Comment: Does you oven ever beep? When our GE oven reaches temperature in baking mode it emits several beeps.

Comment: Does this stove have Sabbath mode? To exit Sabbath mode press and hold the Bake Time and the Set Clock simultaneously for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you set setting control for silent, even if the manual says the timer and temp set will beep, it is not !!! It seems Frigidaire has decided that it is all sounds or no sounds…. Mine is a 27 wall oven FGEW276SPFH… Very disappointing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).